# Is there an equivalent for toPrecision() in Java?

Tags: java

In porting an algorithm from JavaScript to Java, I've run into the problem that I need a replacement for JavaScript's toPrecision(). The problem is that I don't have a clue how small or large the numbers will be, so I can't use a simple NumberFormat with the right format.

Is there a standard class that offers a similar functionality?

EDIT
Here is what I came up with:

```
   double toPrecision(double n, double p) {
        if (n==0) return 0;

        double e = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(n)));
        double f = Math.exp((e-p+1)*Math.log(10));

        return Math.round(n/f)*f;
    }
```

In principle, it does the right thing, but rounding errors completely ruin it. For example,
`toPrecision(12.34567, 3)` returns `12.299999999999997`

EDIT 2
This version works perfectly for 11 out of 12 test cases...

```
   double toPrecision(double n, double p) {
        if (n==0) return 0;

        double e = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(n)));
        double f = Math.round(Math.exp((Math.abs(e-p+1))*Math.log(10)));
        if (e-p+1<0) {
            f = 1/f;
        }

        return Math.round(n/f)*f;
    }
```

But `toPrecision(0.00001234567, 3)` still returns `1.2299999999999999E-5` instead of `1.23E-5`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and [`setScale()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29) method to set the precision

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1.23456789");
System.out.println(bd.setScale(3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
```

**Output**

```
1.235
```

See

- [IDEone demo](http://ideone.com/dMIiW)

Comment: Finding the right scale is something that is missing in your solution, but the use of BigDecimal seems like a good idea.

Comment: This doesn't show three significant digits e.g. "12345678.9 and should return 12300000"

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller
This is wrong solution.
Try this : input 0.0000001
 toPrecision(3)  your code gives answer 0.000
whereas Javascript gives 1.00e-7 i.e 0.0000001

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I came up with for this uses a combination of `java.math.BigDecimal` and `java.math.MathContext` like so.

```
String toPrecision(double number, int precision) {
    return new BigDecimal(number, new MathContext(precision)).toString();
}
```

I'm using this in the [dynjs](https://github.com/dynjs/dynjs) [implementation](https://github.com/dynjs/dynjs/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dynjs/runtime/builtins/types/number/prototype/ToPrecision.java#L32) of [Number.prototype.toPrecision](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.4.7).

Comment: To let it exactly mimic the javascript behavior (especially for scientific notation), we have to convert the result to lower case.

Comment: This actually works with the input of `404279.164` and `4` == `404300.0` which is what I was after.    
`inline fun Double.toPrecision(s : Int) =
        BigDecimal(this, MathContext(s)).toDouble()` in Kotlin

Answer (score 2):

Here's a java solution using String.format.

```
public static String toPrecision(double d, int digits) {
    s = String.format("%."+((digits>0)?digits:16)+"g",d).replace("e+0","e+").replace("e-0","e-");
    return s;
}
```

The .replace is only needed if you want to mimic javascript where it has no leading zero on exponents.  If you are just using it for a rounding then return the value as

```
return Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Here is some unit test code:

```
public void testToPrecision() {
    String s = NumberFormat.toPrecision(1234567.0,5);
    assertEquals("1.2346e+6",s);
    s = NumberFormat.toPrecision(12.34567,5);
    assertEquals("12.346",s);
    s = NumberFormat.toPrecision(0.1234567,5);
    assertEquals("0.12346",s);
    s = NumberFormat.toPrecision(0.1234567e20,5);
    assertEquals("1.2346e+19",s);
    s = NumberFormat.toPrecision(-0.1234567e-8,5);
    assertEquals("-1.2346e-9",s);
    s = NumberFormat.toPrecision(1.0/3.0,5);
    assertEquals("0.33333",s);
    s = NumberFormat.toPrecision(1.0/3.0,0);
    assertEquals("0.3333333333333333",s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `double` with

```
double d = 1.23456789;
System.out.println(Math.round(d * 1e3) / 1e3);
```

prints

```
1.235
```

or

```
System.out.printf("%.3f%n", d);
```

does the same.

---

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(round3significant(12345678.9));
    System.out.println(round3significant(0.0000012345));
}

public static double round3significant(double d) {
    if (d < 100) {
        double divide = 1;
        while(d < 100) {
            d *= 10;
            divide *= 10;
        }
        return Math.round(d) / divide;
    } else {
        double multi = 1;
        while(d > 1000) {
            d /= 10;
            multi *= 10;
        }
        return Math.round(d) * multi;
    }
}
```

prints

```
1.23E7
1.23E-6
```

You can use NumberFormat to only display as a decimal.

Comment: Doesn't meet my requirements. I don't know the scale of the numbers in advance, so in one case, the input might be 12345678.9 and should return 12300000; in another case, 0.00000012345 should return 000000123. There are also rounding problems, see my edited post.

Comment: @ammoQ The code I gave doesn't have rounding issues and gives the same answer as Jigar's. Will revise to handle N significant digits.

Answer (score 1):

This finally works...

```
double toPrecision(double n, double p) {
    if (n==0) return 0;

    double e = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(n)));
    double f = Math.round(Math.exp((Math.abs(e-p+1))*Math.log(10)));

    if (e-p+1<0) {
        return Math.round(n*f)/f;
    }

    return Math.round(n/f)*f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.text.*;  
Class Decimals
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  
        float f = 125.069f;  
        DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("#.##");  
        System.out.println(form.format(f));  
    }
}
```

.## represents upto what decimal places you want
I hope this suits your requirement.

Comment: Not really, see my comment on Peter's answer.